# Using an if statement can I reference any instance of a class with the logic?

Tags: java, object, boolean-logic

Let me give you an example. I have a class - lets say it is a dice class. I have generated a number of dice objects which are rolled and each dice object holds a number... Is there a way I can write an if statement like this (representing in pseudo code):

```
if (any dice object holds a value of one){
  do something;
}
```

This would save me an enormous amount of time - especially as the number of dice objects in play is a non fixed variable in itself.

Comment: Why aren't you storing the dices in an array/list ?

Comment: Actually there are no dice lol this is just an example to illustrate the question...

Comment: But are you saying that if I placed the objects within an array list I could use a blanket if statement somehow ( as above ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you have made a function for this.. this is what will probably work best:

```
List<myClass> myList = new ArrayList<myClass>();

myList.add(______); //add every element upon creation

foreach (myClass myItem: myList) //for each myItem of type myClass within myList
{
    if (__condition__)
    {
        __action__
        break;
    }
}
```

Should work like a charm.

Comment: sorry about the indentation

Comment: Yes the format is a bit confusing but I get the idea and yes that makes perfect sense. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, the foreach loop is great for being non-specific with data :)

Comment: Use a `List<WeakReference<Dice>>` so you can discard no longer used dices (`myList.get(i).get()` being null).

Comment: @user3079666 You can use the code button (looks like curly braces) to mark up source-code — it will give syntax highlighting too :)

Comment: I know, it's just that I wrote the code and then selected it and pressed the code button, I also tried copy-pasting the code after pressing the code button, this was the best result I could get without rewriting from scratch.. I'll try to remember to press it before next time though..